# Split pipe lined string into Rows - Split the empty values also in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, split, pipeline

I have a Pipe lined String like below:

```
'1|Content|2017-02-11|Guest|Gold|||||1903'
```

I want to split the String value into Rows. I found many suggestions by surfing on the net. Most people suggest the function `dbo.Split`.

When I try to split my string using that function:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))RN, Items 
FROM dbo.Split('1|Content|2017-02-11|Guest|Gold|||||1903','|')
```

It gives the result like below:

```
RN  Items
1   1
2   Content
3   2017-02-11
4   Guest
5   Gold
6   1903
```

It skips all the empty values and give only the value holding rows. but in my case if any values where empty, then I want it like below:

```
RN  Items
1   1
2   Content
3   2017-02-11
4   Guest
5   Gold
6   
7
8
9
10  1903
```

Which means, I want the empty vales as ' '. I tried and I can't get it. Please help me to get this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is here use `XML` Method to convert your Pipe lined string data with row :

```
DECLARE @DATA NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @DATA = '1|Content|2017-02-11|Guest|Gold|||||1903';

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) RN,
       split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') [Items]
FROM
(
    SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(@DATA, '|', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS String
) A
CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') AS split(a);
```

Result :

```
RN  Items
1   1
2   Content
3   2017-02-11
4   Guest
5   Gold
6   
7
8
9
10  1903
```

Comment: Oh! It's amazing. Thank you for the support.